# Proving that $x^{2} - x - 1 =0$ under Newton's method converges quadratically

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Say I have the nonlinear equation $x^{2} - x - 1 = 0$, and am using Newton's method to solve it. I learned about the definition of quadratic convergence, namely being

> A seq. $(y_{n})$ converges to $y_{*}$ quadratically if there exists an index $\vec{n}$ and a constant $C \in (0,1)$ such that 
>   \begin{equation*}
>  ||y_{n+1} - y_{*}|| \leq C ||y_{n} - x_{*}|| ^{2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ n > \vec{n}
>  \end{equation*}

and I know how to produce the *general* proof for the quadratic convergence of Newton's method. But I don't know how to prove that a particular case like this one converges quadratically, which I imagine is more simple. How would I go about doing this? Rewriting the iterative equation doesn't seem to help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton's method converges quadratically provided $f'(x^*) \neq 0$. You say you know how to prove this, so just check that $f'(x^*) \neq 0$ in your case.

Also, your definition of quadratic convergence has a typo (the quantity on the right should be squared).

Comment: Oh wow, that's way more simple than proving the definition relation, thanks! And no kidding, that's directly from my slides, I'll edit.